# PostMessage, how to send CTRL BUTTON?

Tags: c#

I'm using C#.

I have process file and I can send via PostMessage for example button 'W'.

I have idea how to make shortcut -> I want to spam each milisecond button "CTRL" (works for button "S" cuz I checked it) and then send "W" button.

But my problem is I don't know how to send 'CTRL" via PostMessage

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can send it as any other key.

The code for Ctrl key is 0x11, so you would do:</s>

```
PostMessage(handle, KEY_DOWN, 0x11 /*CTRL_KEY*/, 0);
```

Sorry, may bad. Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145435/9748260, you cannot do that, and modifier keys cannot be simulated with SendMessage, so I guess this goes for PostMessage too.

Comment: Yeah I tried it and...... it doesn't work! :(

Comment: You should call PostMessage in the following order: PostMessage key_down Ctrl -> PostMessage key_down W -> PostMessage key_up W -> PostMessage key_up Ctrl

Comment: I know. Its easy logic - but my problem is 'sending' CTRL doesn't work just like that